# Recharts Line chart doesn't plot new point on data update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recharts

I have a simple app that allows users to track their weight over time. When a user adds a new entry, the chart updates and is definitely receiving the new data in the props, but isn't plotting the new point.

**Recharts component:**

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    ResponsiveContainer,
    LineChart,
    Line,
    CartesianGrid,
    XAxis,
    YAxis
} from 'recharts';
import moment from 'moment';

const TrackingChart = (props) => {
    const {
        data
    } = props

    let date_min = 0
    let date_max = 0

    if (data.length > 0) {
        date_min = data[0]['date'] - (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)
        date_max = data.slice(-1)[0]['date'] + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
    }

    const dateFormatter = date => {
        // return moment(date).unix();
        return moment(date).format('DD-MMM-YY');
    };

    return (
        <ResponsiveContainer width="100%" height={300}>
            <LineChart data={data}>
                <Line dataKey="weight" stroke="#8884d8" />
                <CartesianGrid stroke="#ccc" />
                <XAxis
                    dataKey="date"
                    scale="time"
                    type="number"
                    domain={[date_min, date_max]}
                    tickFormatter={dateFormatter} />
                <YAxis />
            </LineChart>
        </ResponsiveContainer>
    )
}

export default TrackingChart
```

I know the chart received the new data into props as the x-axis updates, example below:

**Chart before adding new data**
[image: Chart before adding new data point]

**Chart after adding new data**

*data*
date - 31-May-2021
weight - 60

[image: Chart after adding new data]

The `TrackingChart` component definitely has the updated props:
[image]

And the LineChart has the updated data also:
[image]

Any ideas why the chart itself doesn't add the new datapoint to the chart in the DOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of trial and error - I seem to have come up with a solution, which is to pass a dynamic key to each component in the chart object. When a new data point is added, the key will automatically increment by 1, and so the whole object re-renders.

```
return (
        <ResponsiveContainer 
            width="100%" 
            height={300} 
            data={data}
            key={`rc_${data.length}`}>
            <LineChart data={data} key={`lc_${data.length}`}>
                <Line dataKey="weight" stroke="#8884d8" key={`l_${data.length}`}/>              
                <CartesianGrid stroke="#ccc" />
                <XAxis
                    dataKey="date"
                    scale="time"
                    type="number"
                    domain={[date_min, date_max]}
                    tickFormatter={dateFormatter} />
                <YAxis />
            </LineChart>
        </ResponsiveContainer>
    )
```

Eventually, I probably only want to pass in e.g. the last 10 or 20 entries, so will probably need to make the key value a prop to pass down, but the priciple works

Answer (score 1):

This may not solve the problem above, but this may help others.

When passing in live data, use React state. Do not use a const list of objects and append to it. This won't send an event that the chart needs to be updated.

```
const [data, setData] = React.useState([{ name: "", data: 0 }]);
setData((old) => [...old, { name: 'first', data: 1 }]);
```

Then pass data through your props.